# SharePoint 2013:Items were not piked by crawler

Tags: search, search-results

When i check in Search Service Application setting , and open crawl logs i find that item are not picked by crawler and if we search file name or any keyword is not working using Find a file search textbox , i have started many full crawler but no result

Comment: Can you provide more information on the file that isn't being crawled? For example, what is the file extension? When you say you look in the crawl log and the file isn't being crawled, is it just missing from the list of files crawled, or is an error shown against the file? If the latter, what is the error?

Comment: i have found 0 items

Comment: We've seen this kind of issue before when the file type was something that is not crawled by default, for example a .dotm file, or something similar. Can you tell us what the filename and extension are?

Comment: word documents with .docx extention ,

Comment: Is this just a couple of documents in a document library that aren't indexed, or an entire document library? If it's only a few documents in the library, are these documents with different permissions? Can you please check some other documents in the same library in the crawl log (use the URL search for the document library URL to find out whether all/some/no items from the library are being crawled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, make sure that the columns/fields in question have values (Crawl won't pick or index if they have no values). Once this is done, you can either re-index the library (library settings), or re-index the site (site collection feature - search and offline availability)